# show element when clicked and hide again when not active

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have set up a JSFiddle and I am trying to show and hide some text.
When you click on any of the "staff" elements and after the animation I have finishes, the text I have within each of the classes shows. When the user then clicks the "staff" element again, the text hides/fadesout.

My work in progress is here: http://jsfiddle.net/tJugd/3571/

HTML:

```
<div class="slide" style="height:568px;">
    <div class="staff staff-matt" data-hammer="[object Object]">
        <div id="text1"><h1>Lorem Ipsum<h1><p>lorem ipsum dolar<p></div>
    </div>

    <div class="staff staff-shail" data-hammer="[object Object]">
        <div id="text2"><h1>Lorem Ipsum<h1><p>lorem ipsum dolar<p></div>
    </div>

    <div class="staff staff-leah" data-hammer="[object Object]">
        <div id="text3"><h1>Lorem Ipsum<h1><p>lorem ipsum dolar<p></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.slide{
    height:568px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.staff{
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-drag: none;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    touch-action: none;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0px 0px 0px;
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
    width:33%;
    height:568px;
    background:red;
    float: left;
}
.staff-matt{
    background:red;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.298039) 4px 4px 10px 0px;
}
.staff-shail{
    background:white;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.298039) 4px 4px 10px 0px;
}
.staff-leah{
    background:red;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.298039) 4px 4px 10px 0px;
}

#text1, #text3{
    position:relative;
    background-color:white;
    width:50%;
}
```

JS:

```
$('.staff').click(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('clicked')){
        $('.staff').animate({width:'33%'});
    } else {
        $('.staff').not(this).animate({width:'0%'});
        $(this).animate({width:'100%'});
    }
    $(this).toggleClass('clicked');
});
```

Comment: So, whats the question? This seems to be working for me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$('.staff').click(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('clicked')){
        $('.staff').finish().animate({width:'33%'}, 0, function() {
          $("[id^=text]").fadeOut()
        });
    } else {
        $('.staff').not(this).finish().animate({width:'0%'});
        $(this).finish().animate({width:'100%'}, 0, function() {
          $("[id^=text]").fadeIn()
        });
    }
    $(this).toggleClass('clicked');
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/tJugd/3575/

Answer (score 5):

Simply extend your code with the `.fadeIn()` and `.fadeOut()` attribute, targeting your `div` containing text:

```
$('.staff').click(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('clicked')){
        $('.staff').animate({width:'33%'}).find('div').fadeOut(); //Added this
    } else {
        $('.staff').not(this).animate({width:'0%'});
        $(this).animate({width:'100%'}).find('div').fadeIn(); //Added this
    }
    $(this).toggleClass('clicked');
});
```

and to hide the text on load set `div.staff div {display: none}` inside your css.

[**JS FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/tJugd/3576/)